# Get Facebook profile information in a different activity

Tags: android, facebook, firebase

Right after user signs in successfully for the first time in my app using Facebook, he goes to another activity that gets his first and last name. Here is the code in the second activity:

```
if (isSignedInWithFacebook) {
        GraphRequest.newMeRequest(AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken(),
                new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCompleted(final JSONObject object, GraphResponse response) {
                        try {
                            userName = response.getJSONObject().getString("first_name");
                            userLastName = response.getJSONObject().getString("last_name");
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                });
    }
```

After that I add `userName` and `userLastName` to the firebase database. But it doesn't work. According to my tests, the app never enters in the method `public void onCompleted(final JSONObject object, GraphResponse response)`.
What am I doing wrong?
Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone is interested, I understood my mistake. As the request is a Async operation, I needed to do everything (request, parse and save in the database) inside the `try{}` block. And complete with the "parameters" code that was missing. Final code:

```
if (isSignedInWithFacebook) {
        GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken(),
                new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCompleted(final JSONObject object, GraphResponse response) {
                        try {
                            userName = object.getString("first_name");
                            userLastName = object.getString("last_name");
                            usersMap.put("name", userName);
                            usersMap.put("lastName", userLastName);
                            mUsersDatabaseReference.setValue(usersMap);
                            setResult(CompleteSignUpActivity.RESULT_OK, new Intent());
                            finish();
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                });
        Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
        parameters.putString("fields", "first_name,last_name");
        request.setParameters(parameters);
        request.executeAsync();
    } else {
        // ...
    }
```